# Не могу скачать с сайта csv файл

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, кодировка, csv

На сайте `banki.ru` есть ссылка на **Экспорт в Excel**.
Здесь [ссылка](https://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/export.php?LANG=ru&BANK_ID=322&date1=2021-03-01&date2=2021-02-01&IS_SHOW_GROUP=0&IS_SHOW_LIABILITIES=0) на этот **Excel**

Пытаюсь скачать:

```py
id = 322  # номер Сбера
url = f'https://www.banki.ru/banks/ratings/export.php?LANG=ru&BANK_ID={id}&date1=2021-03-01&date2=2021-02-01&IS_SHOW_GROUP=0&IS_SHOW_LIABILITIES=0'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Там виндовая кодировка, кроме того, нужно указать разделитель и пропустить заголовок, тогда данные считаются, но всё-равно там есть ещё разделы и данные не совсем однородны. Но по крайней мере так что-то прочитается:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, encoding='cp1251', sep=';', skiprows=6)
```